# Changed computer, can't access rails app - psql database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql, psql

I'm unable to run an existing rails app locally after changing mac computers. I did a restore from Time Machine backup on my new computer so I wouldn't have to re-add all my apps and information. When I tried to run my app, I received the following error

```
Internal Server Error
FATAL: role "<username>" does not exist
```

I'm pretty sure this has to do with the PSQL database because when I type

```
psql <database name>
```

I receive the following error

```
psql: FATAL:  role "<username>" does not exist
```

I have tried

```
sudo su - postgres
```

and receive the following error

```
su: unknown login: postgres
```

I don't know if this error is because I don't know the password for postgres or if postgres role doesn't exist. I'm not sure what to do from here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. find path: `which createuser`
2. create postgres user: `PATH_FROM_ABOVE/createuser -s postgres`
3. connect `psql -U postgres -d postgres`
4. create missing role: `create user "<username>" password '<password>';`

Comment: the first step will reveal path to `createuser` - all the rest same

Comment: That didn't work. This is the error `createuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  role "<username>" does not exist`

Comment: I can't be sure so I tried uninstalling postgres and reinstalling (view Bew). This did not help either and I now have a new error `could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

Comment: Update: I uninstalled and re-installed postgresql using brew again and it works now!